# Looking for a mechanism similiar to a watch's stem in rotary encoder type form

Tags: potentiometer

The watches stem can be pulled out at two different levels to provide two sets of adjustments of the date and time. Is there something like that in the form of a potentiometer or rotary encoder?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - many oscilloscopes and other pieces of test equipment have rotary encoders with push/pull switches on them.

[An example](http://www.aliexpress.com/product-gs/465746802-11mm-size-metal-shaft-rotary-encoder-with-push-pull-switch-wholesalers.html) of one like this.

Note that I think some rotary encoder classify the outputs of the rotary encoder themselves as push/pull, so this may confuse searching.

As stevenh comments, you may want three levels - free spinning, time at first level and then date. I have one seen a potentiometer on an piece of sound equipment with this functionality, although the neutral position was in the middle, with the in/out being spring return.

Comment: Does this do double action?

Comment: There is an in position and an out position as a switch, along with rotary position.

Comment: I think OP needs 3 in/out positions, like in the watch: normal, set date, set time.

Comment: Possibly, I took it to mean that it just needed two levels.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link. stevenvh was right about three levels, I simply didn't think the normal position was a functional position itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this kind of part before, but it is certainly possible to make (or print if you have access to FDM).  It basically amounts to mounting two pots concentrically with their shafts facing each other.  Place a gear (beveled or not) on each shaft.  Then your knob has a shaft with a gear on it of compatible pitch.  Pull out and it engages one, push in and it engages the other.  And users will not pull it off.  I'd recommend beveled to facilitate the engagement point, and there are probably way nicer ways to deal with this interface.

Another option that's possibly better is to use a friction plate interface (simple rubber might work for you).  Then you have no engagement usability issues and the user can smoothly spin one pot or the other.  Use springs to set a bias so it's normally in the middle, or engaging one of the pots.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the mechanical device would be. I can imagine you would have to make your own, but as far as a nice IC to help you would be a magnetic contactless rotary encoder.

The [AS5030](http://www.ams.com/eng/Products/Magnetic-Position-Sensors/Magnetic-Rotary-Position-Sensors/AS5030) is one of such ICs.

[image]